# Отсутствие подстроки в выбранной строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть следующие строки:

```
NOTIF: element is busy
NOTIF: element PROP is bad
```

Как мне выбрать все строки, которые начинаются с `NOTIF:`, но не содержат `PROP`?

У меня есть пока такой набросок, но сюда попадает строка с `PROP`:

```
/^(NOTIF:.*)$/mg
```

Comment: [`^NOTIF:\s\w+\s(?!PROP).*`](https://regex101.com/r/Gu7mRL/3)

Comment: Круто! Спасибо! Но я бы на всякий случай объединил бы в класс и удалил дублирующий \s, ^NOTIF:[\s\w+](?!PROP).*$  Вообще круто, спасибо, я набросал вариант такой:  ^(?!.*PROP)(NOTIF:.*)$  но он гораздо более трудозатратный, чем ваш. Оформите в ответ?

Comment: ваш вариант более универсальный, т.к. например мой шаблон не отработает на такой строке: `NOTIF: element element PROP is bad`.

Comment: Да, это правда, тогда сам себе отвечу =) Большое спасибо за уделенное время!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если формат достоверно известен, то следует использовать выражения максимально точно описывающие шаблон для лучшего быстродействия.

Например для строк, которые указаны в вопросе очень хорошо подходит вариант предложенный @Эдуард:

```
^NOTIF:[\s\w+](?!PROP).*$
```

Если формат сообщений может иметь разный формат, то стоит использовать более универсальные шаблоны, такие, как этот:

```
^(?!.*PROP)(NOTIF:.*)$
```